# How do I disable Airflow login for authentication and authorization?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I have a fork of apache airflow which I want to run behind a proxy server. All the authentication will be already handled outside airflow, thus I don't want the customers to login with another set of credentials again. Is there any way to completely remove/disable the authentication from airflow.

Basically, I want to get rid of this initial login screen and allow anyone who reaches airflow to have user (not admin) access. [Worst case admin access is also ok.]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nopes. Not yet.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is using docker, this worked for me(airflow 2.0.1):

1. Add a copy of *webserver_config.py* somewhere in your project.
2. Uncomment *AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC* and set 'Admin' as the value.

> ```
> AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin'
> ```

3. Add these settings to your *.cfg* file.

> ```
> [webserver]
> rbac = False
> authenticate = False
> ```

4. In your *Dockerfile*, add the command to copy the *webserver_config.py* into the */home/airflow* directory. e.g:

> ```
> ADD airflow/webserver_config.py /home/airflow
> ```

Once you spin up the pod, config file should be appended to the directory disabling the authentication.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm starting to think Airflow 2.0.1 (or the docker container) has rbac enabled always. Without the webserver_config file you can't control it at all.

Comment: I managed to find some official docs about it [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html#step-5-upgrade-airflow-dags). It's the very last point, just before step 6. rbac is the only auth now, so settings from step 3 are completely removed/disabled.

Comment: were you able to see the flask UI?

Comment: The `rbac` and `authenticate` option no longer exist or no longer documented in [Airflow 2.5.3 config reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.3/configurations-ref.html#webserver) for

Answer (score 4):

Change the authenticate value to false in airflow config file (airflow.cfg) and restart the airflow,

```
# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = False
```

RBAC,

```
rbac = False
```

Comment: @kaxil thanks for correcting, the above is for Web auth not for RBAC. Should we change the rbac = False within the config file to disable the rbac auth?

Comment: were you able to see the new UI after setting rbac to false?

Comment: This doesn't work for airflow 2.x or later. Only works for airflow 1.x

Answer (score 4):

For airflow 2.0.1 and later:

In file: `$AIRFLOW_HOME/webserver_config.py`

add/edit this line (note that by default it says = 'Public' and you need to change it!)

```
AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin'
```

Documentation about this argument:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html#web-authentication

The feature was added in this PR/change: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13191 which was merged into airflow 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I created a new user "Admin" with "Admin" role using the following command, and it works for me:

```
$ airflow users create \
      --username Admin \
      --firstname FIRST_NAME \
      --lastname LAST_NAME \
      --role Admin \
      --email admin@example.org
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to disable the RBAC via an environment variable. Make sure you set the following before starting the webserver:

```
export AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=False
```

See [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/configurations-ref.html?highlight=rbac#rbac) for more details.
The other answers here will all work as well!